# EntityFramework 5 (Model First) and SQLCE: what 'Type' property to store an image?

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce

**Framework:**
In an asp.net MVC 4 project I'm using EntityFramework 5 for the first time and have chosen to use "Model First" due to the ease of model implementation (the ability to generate the db schema once the model is created using the designer). Also, I've chosen to use SQLCE opposed to SQLExpress based on the lightweight nature and requirements of the project.

**Question:**
What is the best property Type selection in the .edmx designer for saving images in the compact sql database? I'm thinking I could convert the image to binary (as I've done in previous web forms projects) but there's no option for varbinary(max).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT
You can define Property Type to "binary" and Map SqlType like "image"

Comment: Ok I've tried this now, and in the .edmx the schema script that is generated saves changes the type from **Byte** (selected in the property type drop-down) to **'tinyint'** (in the script). As far as I can tell from researching 'tinyint' should not be used. Also I currently do have Image type selected in sqlce.

Comment: Ok, o set binary on Type e set MaxLength to Max

Comment: Ahhhh beautiful. So easy I missed it. The following code was generated: [img] image  NOT NULL,